# Add-MailboxFolderPermission throws cast exception AdGroup to AdUser

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Currently I'm getting trouble in setting the calendar permission of a group for all members to Reviewer. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps) and [this blog entry](https://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/2760/managing-folder-level-permissions-for-office-365-groups), it should look like this:

```
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity 3c3558e5-11bd-4ad7-8580-2f0fc7c590d7:\Calendar -GroupMailbox -User "Member@local" -AccessRights Reviewer
```

But unfortunately it throws an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADGroup' to type
>   'Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.ADUser'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-MailboxFolderPermission], InvalidCastException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidCastException,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.StoreTasks.AddMailboxFolderPer
>   mission
>       + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com

Currently no entry is existing on this object for this *user*:

```
Get-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity 3c3558e5-11bd-4ad7-8580-2f0fc7c590d7:\Calendar -GroupMailbox

FolderName           User                 AccessRights                           SharingPermissionFlags
----------           ----                 ------------                           ----------------------
Calendar             Standard             {AvailabilityOnly}
Calendar             Anonym               {None}
Calendar             Owner@local          {Editor}
```

So, any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: I don't think the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` cmdlet has a parameter called `GroupMailbox`. Seems like only `Get-MailboxFolderPermission` has that.. At least, I cannot find it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/add-mailboxfolderpermission?view=exchange-ps&viewFallbackFrom=exchserver-2016)

Comment: Yes, in the documentation it is missing, but auto completion fills it in if you enter `Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Gr` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>

Comment: Then.. what happens if you leave that parameter out on the `Add-MailboxFolderPermission` cmdlet? Is the user not added with 'Reviewer' access rights?

Comment: In that case the identity won't be found, cause it is a group and not a user.